# Nonlinear relationship in logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, nonlinear

I have a binary dependent variable (infection + or -) and both continuous and categorical independent variables.  One continuous independent variable (BMI) seems to be nonlinear in that the lowest and highest BMI are more likely to be + and the BMI values in the middle are less likely to be +.  So when I plot BMI against the proportion that are +, I get U shaped line.  How do I incorporate that into the logistic regression?

Comment: If there's a scientific reason for this, the approach I describe at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/64039/919 would be appropriate.  Otherwise the solution pointed to by @jbowman looks good.