# Which models can be used to explain data with oscillating binary variables?

Tags: logistic, classification, binary-data

The title may be confusing so let me show for demonstration purpose a one-dimensional feature vector

```
x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

and the corresponding labels

```
y = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

A logistic regression model may lead to the following curve

[image]

Now suppose the labels actually look like this

```
y2 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

The corresponding curve after training could look like this:

[image]

As we can see, this model clearly doesn't describe the data well. Is there a "prerequisite" that disallows logistic regression models to be used when the shown case happens? Are there any "standard" models that can describe the data more accurately?

Comment: Search our site for "spline." For another approach see https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/64039/919. BTW, in your first example there is no unique solution: this is a "perfect separation" case.

Comment: That link was pretty helpful, thanks!