# Fitting data taking into account for the spread in data, which are zero for some data points

Tags: python, curve-fitting, measurement-error, scipy, error-propagation

I'm trying to use scipy to fit a $\tanh$ function to some data. The data is of the form $(x_i, y_i)$ for $i=1,\cdots,N$, where $0\leq y_i \leq 1$. I choose $x_i$ to be linearly spaced, such that $x_0=0$ and $x_N=1$. $y_i$ are further obtained from repeating an experiment $M$ times, and checking an event happened or not ($0$ -> did not happen, $1$ -> did happen). The $y$ values are thus a point estimate of probability $p$ for a binomial variable: $y_i=\frac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{j=1}^M X_j$. The standard deviation of $y_i$ is thus $s_i=\sqrt{y_i(1-y_i)/M}$. This is how I end up with data that is spread like $0.5\tanh(a(x-b))+0.5$, which is what I'm trying to fit.

There is more spread in the data if the values are around $0.5$, but many data points at $0$ and $1$ have a standard deviation of $s_i=0$ (such that $X_j=0$ or $X_j=1$ for all measurement repeats $j$).

I tried the method described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39434402/how-to-get-confidence-intervals-from-curve-fit). For that particular code, if I set one of the standard deviations to be `0`, i.e.:

```
y_spread[3] = 0
```

then I get a runtime error:

```
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in divide
```

This makes sense to me, as $s_i=0$, and you can't divide by $0$. Now, the question is, what is the correct way to handle this, statistically? A quick and dirty way could be to set the error to be something small, like `1e-6`, when it is `0`. This does result in a fit, but am I angering the statistics gods?

**EDIT:** added more information as requested in the comments.

Comment: I can't speak for the others, but I was not personally angered by this.

Comment: (more seriously: the problem is that this functions uses the Standard dev to figure out which datapoints it should prioritize fitting. By using a standard dev of 0, you are asking for infinite sensitivity, and the numerical procedure cannot proceed. You should be OK using a small value like 1e-6. To be sure, use a logarithmic range of values, and see how your analysis changes. )

Comment: The nature of your data is unclear: if they "go from 0 to 1," how are you fitting anything?  Surely you need data *pairs,* right?  And in the pairs, which of the components is measured?  One might guess you have $(x_i,y_i)$ pairs with $0\le y_i\le 1$ being your measurements.  If so, how are the $x_i$ determined, what kind of measurement is being used to find the $y_i$ (its statistical properties loom important), and what fitting method are you using?

Comment: @whuber yes, that is the nature of the data. I repeat an experiment at each $x_i$ `20` times, which gives me a bunch of `1`s and `0`s (because I'm checking whether an event happened or not), the average of which is $0\leq y_i \leq 1$. Standard deviation on $y_i$ are thus $s_i=\sqrt{y_i(1-y_i)/20}$. So I choose $x_i$ to be linearly spaced. I'm using the default in `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`, so Levenberg-Marquardt.

Comment: This kind of problem is much better suited for *(Binomial) logistic regression,* not curve fitting.  You can fit specific curves using maximum likelihood.  As an example (with a different function than tanh, but otherwise an identical situation) see my post at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/64039/919. You can also code the log likelihood function and directly optimize it.